# Como colocar o período no javadoc

Tags: javadoc

"Period is missing in javadoc", alguém sabe me dizer o que é o período no javadoc ? seria o @Since ?

alguém sabe me dizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of Tags
Include tags in the following order:

@author (classes and interfaces only, required)
@version (classes and interfaces only, required. See footnote 1)
@param (methods and constructors only)
@return (methods only)
@exception (@throws is a synonym added in Javadoc 1.2)
@see
@since
@serial (or @serialField or @serialData)
@deprecated (see How and When To Deprecate APIs)